# Display one result for category post type

Tags: categories

I'm using taxonomy categories to show my custom post type,  but when I click on it, no page is linked.
How do I create a page to display the results from categories?

I tryed like custom post type:

```
category-portfolio.php
```

but not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create taxonomy-{your-slug}.php template ?
let's say the slug is '**locations**'
so, it will be something like this **taxonomy-locations.php**

if you haven't created yet, create one and the template codes will look like this ,

```
<?php
/**
 * Locations taxonomy archive
 */
get_header();
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="primary-content">
        <h1 class="archive-title"><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title',     $term->name ); ?> News</h1>

        <?php if ( !empty( $term->description ) ): ?>
        <div class="archive-description">
            <?php echo esc_html($term->description); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post clearfix'); ?>>
            <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <div class="content clearfix">
                <div class="post-info">
                    <p><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>
                </div><!--// end .post-info -->
                <div class="entry">
                <?php the_content( __('Full story…') ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--// end #post-XX -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <div class="navigation clearfix">
        <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('« Previous Entries') ?></div>
        <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Next Entries »') ?></div>
    </div>

    <?php else: ?>

    <h2 class="post-title">No News in <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $term->name ); ?></h2>
    <div class="content clearfix">
        <div class="entry">
            <p>It seems there isn't anything happening in <strong><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $term->name ); ?></strong> right now. Check back later, something is bound to happen soon.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!--// end .primary-content -->

<div class="secondary-content">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div><!--// end .secondary-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

here , you can customize as you want & be sure that you use your **slug**.

According to Wordpress Hierarchy,

> If **no** taxonomy-specific template ( taxonomy-{your-slug}.php ) is found,
>
> then the taxonomy that lists pages will use the archive template ( archive.php )

---

> If **no** archive template is found, then the taxonomy that lists pages will use the index template ( index.php )

Comment: my taxonomy have a slug called tag-portfolio:
 `register_taxonomy('tagportfolio', array('project'), array(  'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'tag-portfolio'), ));  `
but i'm trying to create  `taxonomy-tag-portfolio ` but dont works... it still getting index.php

Comment: thanks bro, was the `$taxonomy` string in `<?php register_taxonomy( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args ); ?>` i needed to use. now is working fine :}